# node.js catch block not firing as expected on await

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await, request-promise

My node process exited after logging

```
E    callback: [Function: RP$callback],
E    { serviceName: '....',
E    errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
E    name: 'RequestError',
```

But I thought the below code would catch exceptions and return the defaulted value

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

async function verifyJWT(jwt: string): Promise<any> {

    const userDataPromise = rp({
        uri: ...,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            ...
        }
    });
    const userData = await userDataPromise.catch((err: any) => {
        console.error(`verifyJWT: err`, err)
        return {
            authInfo: {}
        };
    });
    return userData;
}

export default verifyJWT
```

Are there certain types of failures that would not get caught here?
Would it be better to provide a rejection handler in catch on the promise?

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I had gotten myself confused with what I was typing out there; and will update to just async with a catch block.

However; I'm still unclear as to why the future catch didn't capture the error; and why my node process exited?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing standard promise handling with `async/await` style promise handling. You should try to use one or the other, but not both. Using both methods simultaneously is not restricted, but it certainly adds confusion.

This is what `async/await` style promise handling should look like:

```
async function verifyJWT(jwt: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
        return await rp({
            uri: ...,
            method: 'POST',
            json: {
                ...
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`verifyJWT: err`, err);
        return {
            authInfo: {}
        };
    }
}
```

This is what standard promise handling should look like:

```
function verifyJWT(jwt: string): Promise<any> {
    return rp({
        uri: ...,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            ...
        }
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        console.error(`verifyJWT: err`, err);
        return {
            authInfo: {}
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't using `async await` as it should be used

`async await` enables the code to wait for promise response and then move on to the next step. Any error returned by the rest endpoint, is caught by the catch block.

i've posted a sample code below, to show how `async await` would work with `promise`

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var myfun = async ()=>{
    let returnValue = null;
    try{
        let response = await rp("http://localhost:3000/getdata");
        console.log("ajax success");
        returnValue = response;
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("ajax error ",err.message)
        returnValue = err.message;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

**Note** if you want to return any data from `async` function, then the calling function should also be `async` and `await` has to be used while invoking.

[Read more](https://javascript.info/async-await) about `async await`